# Password validation is not allowing special character at the end of the screen

Tags: java, android, regex

I have written a regular expression to validate password on the basis of below conditions.

> *Your password length should be 8 to 20 and must contain at least 2 letters, 1 number and 1 special character. Space not allowed*

My regex is-

```
final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = 
   "^(?=.*[0-9].{1})(?=.*[A-Za-z].{2})(?=.*[@#$%^&+=].{1})(?=\\S+$).{8,}$";
```

It is working in all other cases except if I am entering any special character at the end of the string. Please anyone suggest what is wrong I am doing?

Comment: did you use `trim()` (For string) when matching ?

Comment: Yes, even though it is not accepting.

Comment: The pattern does not meet your specifications.

Comment: problem is your `PASSWORD_PATTERN`

Comment: Yes, this is what the problem is, however I need the solution for this. Where I am doing wrong in the pattern?

Comment: Quantifiers are applied to `.`  and not to the right pattern.

Comment: If one **absolutely** doesn't like regular expressions, one can write a function to iterate over the string and count the number of digits, letters or special characters. `int a=0, d=0, s=0; if (pass.length() < 8 || pass.length() > 20) return false; for (int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++) { char ch = (pass.charAt(i); if (Character.isLetter(ch)) a++; else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) d++; else if (CharacterUtils.isSpecialChar(ch)) /* Need to write your own method to check if char is special */ s++; else if (Character.isWhiteSpace(ch)) return false; } return !(a < 2 || d < 1 || s < 1);`

Answer (score 2):

If one does not like using regular expressions, one can write a function to iterate over the string and count the number of digits, letters or special characters.

```
boolean isValidPassword(char[] pass) {
    int letters = 0, digits = 0, specialChars = 0;
    if (pass.length < 8 || pass.length > 20) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
        char ch = pass[i];
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            letters++;
        }
        else if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            digits++;
        }
        else if (isSpecialChar(ch)) {
            specialChars++;
        }
        else if (Character.isWhiteSpace(ch)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return !(letters < 2 || digits < 1 || specialChars < 1);
}

static boolean isSpecialChar(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '@':
        case '#':
        case '$':
        case '%':
        case '^':
        case '&':
        case '+':
        case '=':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Note that this also **tackles the security problem** when using `String`s, as described by [this article](http://www.codingeek.com/java/strings/why-to-use-char-array-instead-of-string-for-storing-password-in-java-security/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

The pattern does not meet your specifications, because the quantifiers `{1}`, `{2}` are applied to . and not to the right pattern. Also, the last quantifier `{8,}` allows any number of characters from 8, but you need to cap their number to 20. Also, note that `{1}` is totally redundant. Besides, I suggest using the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) inside the lookaheads (check [*Lookahead Example: Simple Password Validation*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password)).

You can use

```
final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = 
  "^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=[^@#$%^&+=]*[@#$%^&+=])\\S{8,20}$";
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ3pL0/1)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - string start
- `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` - there must be at least one digit (after optional non-digits)
- `(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})` - there should be 2 ASCII letters (use `\pL` to match Unicode letters and its counterclass `\PL` to match characters other than Unicode letters)
- `(?=[^@#$%^&+=]*[@#$%^&+=])` - there must be at least 1 special symbol from the set
- `\\S{8,20}` - 8 to 20 non-whitespace symbols
- `$` - end of string

If any of the lookaheads return *false*, the whole match is failed. All of them are executed only once, right after the string start, before the first symbol.

Comment: Nice, you made this regular expression *uncomplicated*.

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. However, will not work if I'll enter any special char like (!, -, ", ;..). So, do we have any set in regex (like for digit it's d similarly for special char) which contain all this special char?

Comment: Use [`^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=[^\\pP\\pS]*[\\pP\\pS])\\S{8,20}$`](https://regex101.com/r/cJ3pL0/2). `\pP` matches punctuation and `\pS` matches symbols.

Comment: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Incorrect Unicode property near index 54:
01-22 14:56:48.483 30115-30115/com.visualoan E/AndroidRuntime: ^(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=[^\pP\pS]*[\pP\pS])\S{8,20}$‌​

Comment: It is Android, it uses a bit different regex than Java. Try using `\\p{P}` or `\\p{IsP}` instead of `\\pP` (similarly for `\\pS`).

Comment: Do those work? If not, try using POSIX classes, too: `\\p{Punct}` and its counter class `\\P{Punct}`. Or `[\\p{Pd}\\p{Ps}\\p{Pe}\\p{Pc}\\p{Pi}\\p{Pf}\\p{Po}]` to match punctuation and `[\\p{Sm}\\p{Sc}\\p{Sk}\\p{So}]` to match all symbols. Add `^` after `[` to make negated character classes.